# Spark 2.3.1 => 2.4 increases runtime 6-fold

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm being forced onto a newer EMR version (5.23.1, 5.27.1, or 5.32+) by our cloud team, which is forcing me up from 5.17.0 w/ **Spark 2.3.1** to **Spark 2.4.x**.  The impetus is to allow a security configuration that forbids Instance Metadata Service Version 1 (although I've tested it without any security config attached, and also tested 5.20.1 which has no option for a security config and also runs spark 2.4.0).

The runtime on a simple ETL job increases 6x on Spark 2.4 (compared to 2.3.1) with no code changes except that spark version.  There's **`leftOuterJoin`**'s on big RDDs in 3 of the 4 stages that have the biggest slowdowns.

**I get no errors, just a 6x increase in time/cost.**  All code is compiled w/ Java 8.

**EDIT**

Confusingly, this is one snippet of offending code where I can reproduce the problem in `spark-shell`, but it does very little in the test run (because the `if` criteria evaluates to `false`).  No joins, no pulling data off disk...  it just takes an existing RDD that's been materialized already, calls it something new and persists to disk.  I persist other RDDs to disk with no problem.  In EMR 5.17 this snippet takes 4.6 minutes, and in 5.23.1 it takes 20 minutes.

```
    val rddWSiteB: RDD[StagedFormat] = {
      if (false) {          // <-- evaluates some stuff that's false
        val site5gnsaLookup = new Site5gnsaLookup(spark, req)
        site5gnsaLookup.rddWithSiteMeta(rddWSite)
      } 
      else {
        rddWSite // <-- this is all that's happening; literally nothing
      }
    }

    rddWSiteB.setName("GetExternalMeta.rddWSiteB")

    // THIS is the problem
    // WHY does serializing/persisting to disk take 10x as long 
    //   in 2.4 vs 2.3?
    rddWSiteB.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
    rddWSiteB.count
```

**END EDIT**

I've read the Cloudera 2.3 => 2.4 migration guide and nothing seems relevant.  Everything else I can find from databricks and blogs, it seems like most of the changes affect SQL and dataframes, but I use JSON and CSV text straight into RDDs.

I'm at a loss.  With no errors, I don't really know how to fix this, but I can't imagine there's any logical reason for a 6x increase in runtime.  I'm not really sure what to do next or what's going on.  **Any ideas to troubleshoot?**

Lastly, I don't think my config is the problem, but in the interest of throwing a bunch of stuff out here in the absence of anything directly useful, I use the following config.

```
    [
      {
        "Classification": "spark-defaults",
        "Properties": {
          "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled": "false",
          "spark.executor.instances": "284",
          "spark.executor.memory": "35977M",
          "spark.executor.memoryOverhead": "4497M",
          "spark.executor.cores": "5",
          "spark.driver.memory": "51199M",
          "spark.driver.memoryOverhead": "5119M",
          "spark.driver.cores": "15",
          "spark.default.parallelism": "4245",
          "spark.shuffle.compress": "true",
          "spark.serializer": "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer",
          "spark.driver.maxResultSize": "0",
          "spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version": "2",
          "spark.network.timeout": "600s",
          "spark.rpc.message.maxSize": "512",
          "spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.capacity": "100000",
          "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max": "256m"
        }
      },
      {
        "Classification": "core-site",
        "Properties": {
          "fs.s3a.endpoint": "s3.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "Classification": "emrfs-site",
        "Properties": {
          "fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption": "true",
          "fs.s3.maxRetries": "20"
        }
      },
      {
        "Classification": "spark-env",
        "Properties": {},
        "Configurations": [
          {
            "Classification": "export",
            "Properties": {
               <Env Variables Removed>
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Classification": "spark-log4j",
        "Properties": {
          "log4j.rootCategory": "INFO, console",
          "log4j.logger.com.tmobile": "DEBUG",
          "log4j.appender.console.target": "System.err",
          "log4j.appender.console": "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender",
          "log4j.appender.console.layout": "org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout",
          "log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern": "%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} [%10.10t] %-5p %-30.30c: %m%n",
          "log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.latency": "WARN",
          "log4j.logger.org": "WARN"
        }
      },
      {
        "Classification": "yarn-site",
        "Properties": {
          "yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled": "false",
          "yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled": "false"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: EMR is its own fork of things, where you should be going through their S3 connector and s3:// URLs. They may have done something with reading/writing data there which boosts parquet performance but which hurts json/CSV reads. why not isolate changes to see where the slowness has surfaced: reading s3 data, writing it back, does it surface when data is on local file:// stores etc.

Comment: I've been able to find one snippet that slows down dramatically, and surprisingly, it does virtually nothing.  The snippet (see **edit** in question) really just uses an already-materialized RDD as-is and caches it to disk.  This takes 4.5x longer, but I've cached other RDDs to disk on the newer images with no problem, so it's confusing why this one chokes and takes 20 minutes instead of 4.

Comment: no idea. FWIW corner case SQL queries which suddenly get a lot slower in a new release is the bane of all SQL engines -its why they all end up with so many switches to tune the query optimizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a matter of persisting to `StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY` while using EBS storage.  The time involved to cache increased about 10x with the move from EMR 5.17 to 5.36.1 (spark 2.3.1 to 2.4.8) while using memory optimized EC2 instances (r5.24xlarge) with EBS storage.

My solution was move to *storage optimized* instances (i4i.32xlarge), which have SSD arrays built in with much faster write speeds.

My jobs run faster now, with the faster caching speeds...  but the instances are about 2x more expensive, so overall my cost is up 40%.

Comment: Was there any other variability in the environment that you did the performance tests in such as different instance types provided to an instance fleet, Spot Instances being taken away in one case and not in another or different inputs?

Comment: nothing that I can think of.  Exactly the same data in each test.  I don't use autoscaling or instance fleets or spot instances.  My clusters used to use 15x r5.24xlarge core instances with EBS storage added, 1x m5.4xlarge master instance, and the config in my original question.  Now I've moved to 15x i4i.32xlarge (w/ SSD arrays instead of EBS) and made the corresponding changes to my config.